# String does not equal another string

Tags: vba

Original string1 looks like this 14.5
I have a procedure that will change the above to 14.50
and place this back into string1.

if I have string2 = string 1,  string2 will be 14.5

Not what I want. I have tried converting string1 to a numeric with the Val function and then resetting it with the Str function. does not work.

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you post your code.  Guessing that you're converting to a `Variant` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
num = FormatNumber(CDbl(string1), 2)
string1 = CStr(num)
```

'num' is just a placeholder here for the converted value (14.50), you don't need a second string.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  `FormatNumber` already returns a `String`, so there isn't a need to cast `num` unless all of the variable types are already messed up and there's implicit casting going on: `Debug.Print TypeName(FormatNumber(CDbl(42), 2))`

Comment: Thanks, Works great

Comment: Thanks. Works great.

Comment: I have to take back my thanks. I had created an invoice where the total for each row is shown and of course a grand total is also shown. After a third entry is made the grand total reverts back to not displaying the grand total correctly.  ex 14.50 now again shown as 14.5

Comment: That wouldn't be the fault of my solution. All it does is add an extra decimal place. As Comintern said, post your entire code if you want meaningful feedback.